# Cocoa MVC implementation

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, architecture

I'm not very experienced with Cocoa but I am with MVC and coding in general.
I come from an ActionScript background, so I'm very familiar with [PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/).

I understand the fundamentals of Cocoas version of MVC. All works fine with very tiny applications. But how do I have to setup my architecture for larger applications? How should I manage my model objects and the communications between all the parts? How do I pass my instances between them. Is it a good idea to use Singletons which map my instances?

For now I used the Objective C PureMVC implementation. For those who know PureMVC: Instead of using Mediator subclasses, I've created ViewController subclasses which implement the IMediator Protocol, because in my opinion Mediators and ViewControllers are almost the same and I do not lose all the ViewController stuff.

But I definitely want to go an Apple approved and well-established way for future projects. Can anyone give my some good architecture approaches?

Comment: I am sorry, but I’m afraid this question is not a good fit for the Stack Overflow Q&A format, as it is *very* broad.

Comment: yes I agree with you. But maybe someone can link me to any good resource for exactly this topic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer some projects from [Apple developer](http://developer.apple.com/) site.
[Model-View-Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)